# Alternative ways to store user preferences without using a database nor cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, backbone.js

I have an frontend application(using Backbone) which is running inside an iframe on another domain. I need to store some user preferences so that next time the user is on the application, his previous settings/state are already set. I have used cookies for that but this does not work in Safari/iOS which disables cross-domain cookies by default.

Are there some other ways to store these preferences that is cross-browser and cross-domain and that does not require a database store.

Comment: Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn localStorage is also disabled cross-domain on safari

Comment: try using Storage Access API